# Oauth2 authentication

Tags: java, spring, web-services

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

            clients.inMemory()
           .withClient("javadeveloperzone")
                   .secret("secretcode")
                   .accessTokenValiditySeconds(2000)        // expire time for access token
                   .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(-1)         // expire time for refresh token
           .scopes("read", "write")                         // scope related to resource server
                   .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token");      




}
```

I use this code but I want to accessTokenValiditySeconds read from my data base please help me for that i new in Spring web service authentication. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can @Autowired a service/dao and make a request to read value from database. What's your problem ?

Comment: i read value from database but Actually i want to token expiry dynamically changed after database value changed  can you help me for that?

Comment: If you don't want your server keeping sessions in memory you can use :
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

But i'm not sure of what you really want to do. Maybe you should update your question and explain exacly what is the process you have in mind.

Comment: once token receive with validity can i changed validity? if yes how?

Comment: If you talk about JWT token, they are meant to be signed with RSA (or other algorithms), so you are supposed to check there validity with public key.